# Matlab plot3 see-through element

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab

I am plotting the following Stewart platform in Matlab using `plot3` and `fill3`.

The green line that I have marked in the red circle is not supposed to be visible because it is behind the top layer.

How can I make the top layer to not be see-through?

[image]

Comment: [This](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/alpha.html) might help.

Comment: Thanks. `alpha(1)` doesn't solve the problem but `alpha(0.9)` makes it bearable.

Comment: Doesn't it help to invert the order in which you plot the parts of your image? In particular, plotting/filling the upper triangle after the the circled green line?

Comment: Also, a minimal working example would be useful.

Comment: Done, I didn't see your comment. Please, next time consider using and @ mention.

Comment: I meant @macydanim =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [link](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/alpha.htmlA) to the matlab help for the command `alpha`, which "sets transparency properties for objects in current axes".

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't it help to invert the order in which you plot the parts of your image? In particular, plotting/filling the upper triangle after the the circled green line?